# how does assertequals work for domain objects?

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-2.2

In this piece of integration test code it is asserting a list of models. How does `assertEquals` work for models. Does it check if both models have same id?

```
def model = controller.list()
assertNull model.selection.endDate  
assertNull model.selection.startDate
assertEquals([raceGroup], model.compositeEvents)
```

Comment: If you implement `equals()/hashCode()` in your domain class to check only ids, then yes

Comment: and what if there is no equals and hashcode implementation?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500091/grails-gorm-what-is-the-default-equals-implementation-in-gorm

Comment: @injecteer: Earn some reputations and create an answer of your comments.